# Java LinkedList inserting Object at index

Tags: java, methods, linked-list, inner-classes, singly-linked-list

I am having a bit of trouble understanding how to place an object in a linked.
In this case, if there is already an object at the specific index, it won't replace it (that is for another method). I guess I am having trouble understanding how to get to a specific index, retrieve the data from that index, and then either put data there and connect the nodes or tell the user there is already an object there.

Here is my code:

```
public class CourseList {

    private Coursenode head;
    int currentSize;

    public void insertAtIndex(Course c, int index) {

        Coursenode insert =new Coursenode(c,head); 
        Coursenode temp = new Coursenode();

        if (index > currentSize - 1 || index < 0) {
            throw (new IndexOutOfBoundsException());
        }


        for(int x = 0; x < index; x++) {
            if (insert.getNext()!= null) {
                temp = insert;
                insert.setNext(insert);
                insert.setData(temp.getData());
            }
            if (insert.getNext() == null && x == index) {
                insert.setNext(insert.getNext());
            }
            if (insert.getNext() != null && x == index) {
                System.out.println("There is already a Course at that Index");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the inner class Coursenode:

```
public class Coursenode {

    private Course data;
    private Coursenode next;

    public Coursenode() {
        this.data = null;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public Coursenode(Course course, Coursenode next) {
        this.data=course;
        this.next= next;
    }

    public Coursenode(Coursenode x) {
        this.data = x.getData();
        this.next = x.getNext();
    }

    public Course getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Course data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Coursenode getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Coursenode next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    //Clone method
    public void clone(Coursenode new_cn){ 
         new_cn = new Coursenode (this.getData(),this.getNext());
    }
}
```

Any thought would be appreciated, I suspect I am getting lost within the head reference between nodes but I can't quite figure out how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways (assuming positive `index` values) to make an insertion at an index in a linked list:

1. At the head (`index == 0`)
2. After the tail (`index >= currentSize`)
3. In the middle (at an occupied index) (`index > 0 && index < currentSize`)

There may be a tendency to think that inserting at the tail is another case, but later we'll see that insertion at the tail is the same as an insertion in the middle, because the tail will be slid forward.

If the insertion is at the head, you need to set the `next` of the inserted node to the old `head` and then set `head` to the inserted node:

```
private void insertAtHead(Course course) {
    Coursenode insertedNode = new Coursenode(c, head);
    head = insertedNode;
}
```

If the insertion occurs past the tail, a common way of dealing with this is to throw some sort of exception, such as an [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html):

```
throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Cannot insert course after the tail of the course list");
```

If the insertion occurs at an occupied index, the existing node (and all nodes after the existing node) must be pushed forward. This means that the `next` of the inserted node must be set to the node that currently occupies the index and the `next` of the node previous to the node at the current index must be set to the inserted node. In essence, the inserted node is fused into the list. To do this, the list must be traversed until the occupied node is found:

```
private void insertAtOccupied(Course course, int index) {
    Coursenode previous = null;
    Coursenode current = head;

    for (int i = 1; i <= index; i++) {
        // Track the previous and current nodes
        //   previous = node at i - 1
        //   current = node at i
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
    }

    Coursenode insertedNode = new Coursenode(c, current.next);
    previous.next = insertedNode;
}
```

Pulling these cases together, we can create the following logic:

```
public void insertAt(Course course, int index) {

    if (index == 0) {
        insertAtHead(course);
    }
    else if (index >= currentSize) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Cannot insert course after the tail of the course list");
    }
    else if (index > 0 && index < currentSize) {
        insertAtOccupied(course, index);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the call to `Coursenode` in `insertAtOccupied` should be `current` rather than `current.next`, otherwise the operation is a replacement, not an insertion.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in a linkedlist if

> index < linkedlistsize

then there is an object already in a linkedlist. If you have a null node in node.next that how you know you have reached the end of your linked list.

```
public class CourseList {

    private Coursenode head;
    int currentSize;

    public void insertAtIndex(Course c, int index) {

        Coursenode insert =new Coursenode(c,head); 
        Coursenode temp = new Coursenode();

        if (index > currentSize - 1 || index < 0) {
            throw (new IndexOutOfBoundsException());
        }

        //tempnode = head;
        for(int x=1; x< index;x++) {
         //tempnode = tempnode.next;
        }
        //nodeatindex = tempnode;
        //you can get details of the node
}
```

Hope this helps!